# Find address at another activity

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-activity, geocoding

I am doing a Google map application.
I wrote a function to find address.
When I wrote code at main activity, it's work.
But when I wrote at another activity. It's always force close app.

What is wrong and how I can fix it?

This is my log:

```
11-24 08:56:52.659: E/AndroidRuntime(16334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zzzzzz/com.example.zzzzzz.Direction}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my mainactivity code find address:

```
        // find address
    final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);

    final EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAddress);
    Button btAddress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAddress);
    btAddress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Ten = ed.getText().toString();
            try {
                List<Address> l = geocoder.getFromLocationName(Ten, 5);
                if (l != null && l.size() > 0) {
                    int lat = (int) (l.get(0).getLatitude() * 1000000);
                    int lon = (int) (l.get(0).getLongitude() * 1000000);
                    GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);

                    p = pt;
                    MapOverlay mar = new MapOverlay();
                    listOfOverlays.add(mar);

                    mv.getController().setZoom(17);
                    mv.getController().setCenter(pt);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v("Loi: ", "Loi 1 cua tui ne");
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is my function start other activity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
        //about
        Intent about = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.About");
        startActivity(about);
        break;
    case R.id.setting:
        //setting
        Intent setting = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.Setting");
        startActivity(setting);
        break;
    case R.id.direction:
        //direction
        Intent direction = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.Direction");
        startActivity(direction);
        break;
    case R.id.MyLocation:
        //mylocation
        //Intent mylocation = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.MyLocation");
        //startActivity(mylocation);
        initLocationManagerV2();
        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint find = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6), (int)(lng*1E6));
        mv.getController().animateTo(find);
        mv.invalidate();
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

this is my Direction activity:

```
public class Direction extends Activity {

MainActivity maintest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.direction);

    // find address
    final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(maintest);

    final EditText edMylocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edMylocation);
    final EditText edEndpoint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edEndpoint);
    Button btDirection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDirection);

    btDirection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String endpoint = edEndpoint.getText().toString();


            try {
                List<Address> l = geocoder.getFromLocationName(endpoint, 5);
                if (l != null && l.size() > 0) {
                    int lat = (int) (l.get(0).getLatitude() * 1000000);
                    int lon = (int) (l.get(0).getLongitude() * 1000000);
                    GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);

                    //p = pt;
                    //MapOverlay mar = new MapOverlay();
                    //listOfOverlays.add(mar);

                    maintest.mv.getController().setZoom(17);
                    //maintest.mv.getController().setCenter(pt);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v("Loi: ", "Loi 1 cua tui ne");
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

//////////////////////////////////////
this is function i do (AndylandDev):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String endpoint = data.getStringExtra("endpoint");
        final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
        try {
            List<Address> l = geocoder.getFromLocationName(endpoint, 5);
            if (l != null && l.size() > 0) {
                int lat = (int) (l.get(0).getLatitude() * 1000000);
                int lon = (int) (l.get(0).getLongitude() * 1000000);
                GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);

                p = pt;
                //MapOverlay mar = new MapOverlay();
                //listOfOverlays.add(mar);

                mv.getController().setZoom(17);
                mv.getController().setCenter(pt);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.v("Loi: ", "Loi 1 cua tui ne");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your class name and how is it defined in the manifest? According to the logcat, it doesn't really follow the recommended naming convention. Also, it sounds like the activity isn't defined correctly in the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So

```
new Geocoder(maintest);
```

is likely throwing a NullPointerException because you're maintest variable is null.  In general, activities should never have direct access to each other like this.  This would be the proper way to do it:

When you start the Direction Activity:

```
case R.id.direction:
    //direction
    Intent direction = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.Direction");
    startActivityForResult(direction, 1);
    break;
```

in onCreate() of Direction Activity

```
...

btDirection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("endpoint", edEndpoint.getText().toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
});

...
```

And then add this method to MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    String endpoint = data.getStringExtra("endpoint");
    //do whatever with it
}
```

Comment: i got :11-24 13:26:53.969: E/AndroidRuntime(30137): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zzzzzz/com.example.zzzzzz.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
now!i post my funtion on bottom of my question! can you see for me? hix! i am beginner

Comment: could you post the whole stack trace?